# Custom spinner adapter simple_spinner_dropdown_item not displaying correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I am getting data from an SQLite database and assigning them to data objects. I am using a custom spinner adapter (implements `SpinnerAdapter`) to put them in spinners so as to override the `getItem()` and `getItemId()` methods. However, the `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` is not displaying correctly (screenshots from my Galaxy Tab 2 10.1):

[image: Wrong spinner from data object]

By contrast this is a spinner which is populated from an array in `R.array` (the correct look/size):

[image: Proper spinner from R.array]

Done by this code:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.quote_prices, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I am unable to get this look by implementing/extending some sort of adapter (I have also tried extending `BaseAdapter` to no avail). This is the code for my spinner adapter as it stands:

```
public class MySpinnerAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    /**
     * The internal data (the ArrayList with the Objects).
     */
    private List<? extends BaseDO> data;

    public MySpinnerAdapter(Context context, List<?extends BaseDO> data){
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the Size of the ArrayList
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return data.get(position).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, null);
        }
        ((TextView) convertView).setText(data.get(position).toString());
        return convertView;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) View.inflate(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, null);
        textView.setText(data.get(position).toString());
        return textView;
    }


    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {

    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {

    }

    public List<? extends BaseDO> getData() {
        return data;
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that this is called using

```
spnnrTerm.setAdapter(new MySpinnerAdapter(getActivity(), termList));
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I know this question is old but I've been having the same issue and have just figured out the problem. After examining the source for [ArrayAdapter.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java) I noticed it was passing the ViewGroup to the inflater and I wasn't. This was the problem all along.

```
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, parent, false);
        }
        ((TextView) convertView).setText(data.get(position).toString());
        return convertView;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) View.inflate(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, null);
        textView.setText(data.get(position).toString());
        return textView;
    }
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to dig up the app from somewhere... I'll get back to you.

Comment: I got it to work, good spot in the source. I've edited the code slightly since the `inflate()` function in the `getView()` method doesn't exist as you specified it. In fact, it gave me errors when supplying parent to that function, so in the end all that was necessary was to change the first `inflate()`.