# Spinner on dropdown appears event

Tags: android, spinner

I want to perform some actions on the appearance of a `DropDown` spinner.

I cannot find any way to get "onShowListener"

Is there such a listener ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this implementing your own SpinnerAdapter.

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Hide the keyboard here
}
```

This method is only invoked when the spinner appears.

You can find an example of a custom SPinnerAdapter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567986/custom-spinner-adapter-simple-spinner-dropdown-item-not-displaying-correctly)

Comment: getDropDownView is called for every visible item on the screen. I don't want to have my show method called a gazilion times ;)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution would be to use the [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html). But maybe it gives you some unwanted side effects, because it gets also called, when you click on a list item.

BTW You can't set an OnClickListener, because it gives this Exception:

*"java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead"*

```
        spinner.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Hide your Keyboard
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

setOnItemSelectedListener is available which will give you which item is selected

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                            View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: i do not care which item was selected, i want to hide the keyboard when the spinner appears

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried adding setOnClickListener and then check if spinner isShown or not