# How to add customize Spinner?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I am working on a project where I have to implement a spinner. My spinner code is below:

```
  ArrayAdapter stringArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, 
  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, CatagoryName);

        // create a spinner
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        // add adapter to spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter);
        // create listener and add to spinner
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // put code which recognize a selected element
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Basically, I want to use my custom spinner layout at

```
   ArrayAdapter stringArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, 
   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, CatagoryName);
```

R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown is not what I want. How to replace this layout with mine?

Comment: Simply pass this `R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown` instead of `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item` inside `ArrayAdapter`.And then do `setDropDownViewResource`.

Comment: Did you read accepted answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567986/custom-spinner-adapter-simple-spinner-dropdown-item-not-displaying-correctly

Comment: What custom layout? Did you make one? Is it not working when you actually do use it?

Comment: I do made one.. But when I am using it like R.layout.custom_spinner then its not working.. It showing error...

Comment: http://abhiandroid.com/ui/custom-spinner-examples.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is worked for me,
 firstly define spinner items in strings.xml which in values directory as above,

```html
 
  <string-array name="spinner_array">
        <item>item1</item>
        <item>item2</item>
        <item>item3</item>
    </string-array>
```

then try above code,

```
 Spinner customSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.spinner_array, R.layout.custom_spinner_dropdown);

    customSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    String[] CatagoryName = {"A","B","C","D"};
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> langAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), R.layout.your_layout, CatagoryName);
    langAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown);
    spinner.setAdapter(langAdapter);
```

Comment: But what about the CatagoryName.. My arraylist is in CatagoryName which I am showing in the spinner??

Comment: Try Updated Code.